# How to give id to the input text created by the autocomplete tag in the jQuery mobile in phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, autocomplete, cordova

I am creating an app in which I have use autocomplete as we know that the while creating an autocomplete using jQuery mobile it creates an input field with data-type='search'. Know as per the example given in the [jQuery mobile site](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/autocomplete/autocomplete-remote.html) after selecting the data from the list it do nothing so I had return a code to hide the list and set the selected value to the input text. Know the issue is if I am using only one autocomplete in page then it sets the selected data properly but if i am using more than 1 autocomplete than how can i set the selected text to input text i tried to give an id but if I give the id then it set the same id for all the autocomplete text fields. What I want is to give different id to all the input field created by the autocomplete in the jQuery mobile.

Here is the code for getting the selected data from list:

```
 $('ul>li').click(function(){
    var textval=$(this).text();
    $('input[data-type="search"]').val(textval);// this will set the selected data to input field
    //hide the serach list after selection is done  
    $.mobile.activePage.find("[data-role=listview]").children().addClass('ui-screen-hidden'); });
```

Comment: `$('ul').prev('form').find('input').attr('id', 'whatever');`

Comment: @Omar thanks for the answer but if i put it above the $('#demopage').trigger('create') than it does nothing. And if it use it after the trigger it applying the id to fields but i want to apply it before the trigger function.

Comment: @Omar is it possible to set this id when the input field is created and not in the onclick or listbeforefilter function